# How to build nodejs app from Gitlab using Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

How to build nodejs app from Gitlab using Google Cloud Build.
could you help to write script that will get app from gitlab and build it on Cloud Build

Comment: Which part is blocking for you? How to authenticate to gitlab? How to manage the event (webhooks)? How to build a nodeJS app and deploy it? On which service? in a container?

Comment: If you are looking for a way of continuous deployment from Git using Cloud build, you may want to look at this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build). If it's not what you are looking for, please elaborate a bit more on your goal and answer @ guillaumeblaquiere's questions in the previous comment"